# read structured array from ascii file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, io

I have an ASCII text file (which is in a given format that I cannot change) with the content

```
previous data...
#
# some comment
2 a -0.9989532219119496
1 b 1.8002219998623799
1 c 0.2681232137509927
# 
some other things...
```

and I would like to read that file into an array with a custom dtype (a ["structured array"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays)). It all works when the file is binary (remove the `sep="\n"` below), but it fails when the file is ASCII:

```py
import numpy as np
import string

# Create some fake data
N = 3
dtype = np.dtype([("a", "i4"), ("b", "S8"), ("c", "f8")])
a = np.zeros(N, dtype)
a["a"] = np.random.randint(0, 3, N)
a["b"] = np.array([x for x in string.ascii_lowercase[:N]])
a["c"] = np.random.normal(size=(N,))

print(a)

a.tofile("test.dat", sep="\n")
b = np.fromfile("test.dat", dtype=dtype, sep="\n")

print(b)
```

```
ValueError: Unable to read character files of that array type
```

Any hints here?

(The file contains other data as well, so in real life I'm using a file handle instead of a filename string, but I suppose this doesn't matter much here.)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html#numpy.fromfile): Do not rely on the combination of `tofile` and `fromfile` for data storage, as the binary files generated are are not platform independent. In particular, no byte-order or data-type information is saved. Data can be stored in the platform independent `.npy` format using [`save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) and [`load`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) instead.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: from the [`tofile` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile): *This is a convenience function for quick storage of array data. Information on endianness and precision is lost, so this method is not a good choice for files intended to archive data or transport data between machines with different endianness. Some of these problems can be overcome by outputting the data as text files, at the expense of speed and file size.*

Comment: The `save/load` pair are easier to use.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. Unfortunately, I cannot change the file format, otherwise I'd use some entirely different (e.g., `load`/`save`). I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Hold on!  When you first posted this, the text included `()` and `b'str'`, as produced by `tofile`.  Now you show a simple csv format.  `np.genfromtxt` with `dtype=None` can easily handle that.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the hint. I've added some context on what the file actually looks like. I'd love to use`genfromtxt`, but I can't see how I can make it read a given number of lines only.

Comment: `genfromtxt` has a `maxrows` parameter.  Also instead of a file name, you can give it anything that feeds it lines.  For testing I often use a list of lines.  In general `genfromtxt` gives you a lot more control over how a text file is read that `fromfile`.  Of course there's nothing wrong with reading the file yourself, splitting the lines, and making a list of lists, and from that an array.

Comment: @hpaulj If you want to promote the comment to answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [286]: txt = """previous data... 
     ...: # 
     ...: # some comment 
     ...: 2 a -0.9989532219119496 
     ...: 1 b 1.8002219998623799 
     ...: 1 c 0.2681232137509927 
     ...: #  
     ...: some other things...""".splitlines()
```

Using parameters as noted in my comment:

```
In [289]: np.genfromtxt(txt, skip_header=1, max_rows=3, dtype=None, encoding=None)                                                                    
Out[289]: 
array([(2, 'a', -0.99895322), (1, 'b',  1.800222  ),
       (1, 'c',  0.26812321)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<U1'), ('f2', '<f8')])
In [290]: _.shape                                                               
Out[290]: (3,)
```